# How can we share a video or you tube link with LinkedIn PHP API?

Tags: php, youtube, linkedin-api

I am trying to  `share a YouTube link on user wall with LinkedIn PHP API`. I am trying to this with '`linkedin_3.2.0.class.php`'. I am able to post you tube link on `LinkedIn` and it's playing also. but my problem is that, **when user clicks on title it will redirect to user's on you tube not on my Facebook app url**. I am sharing my scree and code also with you guys.. If possible guide me where I am doing wrong.

**`Here is my PHP Code:`**

```
<?php
$OBJ_linkedin = new LinkedIn($API_CONFIG);
$OBJ_linkedin->setTokenAccess($_SESSION['oauth']['linkedin']['access']);

$content                        = array();
$content['comment']             = $_SESSION['linkedin']['message'];
$content['title']               = $_SESSION['linkedin']['title'];
$content['submitted-url']       = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj7kFvk-T7g';
$content['submitted-image-url'] = Config::BASE_URL . $_SESSION['linkedin']['image'];
$content['description']         = $_SESSION['linkedin']['message'];
$content['url']                 = Config::APP_URL;
$content['source'] = Config::APP_URL;
$private           = TRUE;

$response          = $OBJ_linkedin->share('new', $content, $private);

if ($response['success'] === TRUE) {
    header('Location: ' . Config::APP_URL);
    die();
} else {
    echo "Error sharing content:<br /><br />RESPONSE:<br /><br /><pre>" . print_r($response, TRUE) . "</pre><br /><br />LINKEDIN OBJ:<br /><br /><pre>" . print_r($OBJ_linkedin, TRUE) . "</pre>";
}
```

**`Here is my Screen shot:`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update with me:

1. LinkedIn not provide yet 2 link/url share option.
2. We can share only one link/url by LinkedIn share API.
3. If you share YouTube link by share, then user will get YouTube video
   on wall and they can play video over there. But, when user 
   clicks on title link, he/she will redirect on YouTube page not your's.
4. If you share your url then you cant show YouTube video on user's
   wall.
5. Best thing is that if we are sharing our site url then we have
   option to set an image as thumbnail. This is good because user can
   see what we are trying to say ;)

Comment: This means, there is no method which allows to upload media files on LinkedIn. As in, Twitter/FB API provides the methods to upload images and videos. Please let me know if you have any information on this.

Comment: Hi, @Paarth.. According to LinkedIn you can only upload below files on LinkedIn:
Presentations: pdf, ppt, pps, pptx, ppsx, pot, potx (Powerpoint), odp (OpenOffice)
Documents: pdf, doc, docx, rtf (MSOffice), odt
Images: png, gif, jpg, jpeg with Maximum file size: 100MB. There is no way to upload media files instead of that you can use links.